# Pandas GroupBy drop_duplicates on specific group

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

### Question

Consider the following dataframe:

```
In [143]: import pandas as pd
In [144]: from io import StringIO

In [145]: s = """ Mode    Value
0   0   9
1   0   10
2   1   7
3   1   6
4   1   8
"""

In [146]: _df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\t', index_col=0)

In [147]: _df
Out[147]: 
    Mode  Value
0      0      9
1      0     10
2      1      7
3      1      6
4      1      8
```

### The desired output

I'd like to group the data by the `Mode` and get the last value of particular group. The goal is to only apply `drop_duplicates` in the group of `Mode == 0`.

```
   Mode  Value
1     0     10
2     1      7
3     1      6
4     1      8
```

### Trials

The logic that I could think of is to chain `groupby` method with `last` method or `tail`. However, I'm not sure where I should put the conditions into the chains.

```
In [161]: _df.groupby('Mode').last()
Out[161]: 
      Value
Mode       
0        10
1         8
```

I can use the `pd.concat` to produce the desired output, however, I'm thinking about if there is  a better way to do this in pandas?
Another reason is that the real data I'm dealing with have multiple grouping criteria, so, in my opinion, it would be better to have a more straightforward chaining methods instead of `concat`-ing the dataframe.
Thanks peeps!

```
In [184]: pd.concat([
     ...:     _df[_df.Mode == 0].drop_duplicates(subset=['Mode'], keep='last'),
     ...:     _df[_df.Mode != 0]
     ...: ])
Out[184]: 
   Mode  Value
1     0     10
2     1      7
3     1      6
4     1      8
```

Comment: Try `groupby` on a subset of dataframe and `concat` the other remaining dataframe

Comment: Hi @AjayA, sorry I don't really get why we need to `groupby` in a subset of the dataframe. Would it be different with the `concat` method I added by the end of the question? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can also sort_values and check `duplicated` with an additional condition which checks if Mode == 0 :

```
_df[~(_df.sort_values(['Mode','Value']).duplicated('Mode',keep='last') 
      & _df['Mode'].eq(0) )]
```

---

```
   Mode  Value
1     0     10
2     1      7
3     1      6
4     1      8
```

Comment: Hi @anky, since the data i'm dealing with is a transactional data, the order of the data is important to me. As far as I'm concerned, I do not see the requirements of sorting it with `sort_values` prior to masking it out. Perhaps I missed something, but could you elaborate why we need to sort it out first? Thanks

Comment: @TotoLele You can disregard the sort values and continue using the same solution. I kept it for readers who might interpret last as max (on the value column)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) in inverted mask in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~(df.duplicated(subset=['Mode'],keep='last') & (df['Mode'] == 0))]
print (df)
   Mode  Value
1     0     10
2     1      7
3     1      6
4     1      8
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, I've seen the first solution you came with using a helper column. I'll mark @anky 's as the accepted answer since both of you came up with the same solution afterwards. For peeps looking at this comment, check the edited version of this answer for another solution with a helper column. Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorting is not necessary in my case.

Comment: That's not the reason. The reason is I saw the timestamp of the post. anky posted few minutes before you edited the answer. I might be wrong, please CMIIW

Comment: Thanks jezrael, I know you since you always provided me with superb answers. Thanks for all the supports.